# Is there a way to get input data from createElement() function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
 let x_rows = 2;
 addNewRow = () => {
     
    let bundle_of_rows = document.createElement("div");

    while (x_rows - 1 >= 0) {
      let a_row = document.createElement("input");
      bundle_of_rows.appendChild(a_row);
      x_rows--;
    }

    document.getElementById("sub-main").appendChild(bundle_of_rows);
  };
```

This code would create something like this...

```
<div>
   <input></input>
   <input></input>
</div>
```

and, then it would append it to "sub-main"

```
<div id="sub-main">
  <div>
     <input></input>
     <input></input>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to store the values of "input" like onChange that should update this.state = {input: ""}. Is there a way to give attributes to these inputs?
/must use createElement() /

Comment: You probably shouldn’t be using DOM methods with react, since it controls that with its virtual DOM.

Comment: how would you add elements using other than createElement() in react? I tried attaching  JSX to a variable then tried to append... It displayed an error stating that "JSX" is not a node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add it as an attribute to your created `a_row` object:

```
let a_row = document.createElement("input");
a_row.onChange = () => {
    console.log('do onchange things');
};
```

Or you can also add an event listener:

```
a_row.addEventListener('change', () => {
  console.log('do onchange things');
});
```